# TypeScript keyof and Indexer compatibility?

Tags: typescript

I have a method signature which expect a second argument of `keyof Array<...>`.
Since `Array` interface defines an indexer `[n: number]: T;` I'd expect to be some way to refer to some index in the method.

But I can't find how.
I tried the following:

```
MyMethod(myArray, 0); // Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type ...
MyMethod(myArray, [0]); // Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type ...
MyMethod(myArray, '0'); // Argument of type '"0"' is not assignable to parameter of type ...
MyMethod(myArray, '[0]'); //  Argument of type '"[0]"' is not assignable to parameter of type ...
```

And none is working.

Answer (score 3):

You could always try:

```
function myFun<T>(arr: Array<T>, index: number) {
  return arr[index];
}
```

`keyof Array<...>` refers to all property names of arrays, like `length`, `toString`, `push`, `pop`, etc. Number indices aren't part of the `Array` interface in the same manner because they're a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html):

```
interface Array<T> {
  length: number;
  toString(): string;

   ... etc ...

  [n: number]: T;
}
```

Consider a simpler interface:

```
interface Arr<T> {
  [n: number]: T;
}

const variable: keyof Arr<number>; // variable is of type "never"
```

This is actually a shortcoming of the language. See also [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13715):

> We can not list all these numeric string literals (effectively). `keyof Container<T>` would be `number | numericString` with `numericString` as type of all numeric string literals with a corresponding number literal. `number | string` wouldn't be correct because not every `string` is a `numericString`. Also not every string sequence of digit characters is a `numbericString` since number has a maximum and minimum value.